# Composite primary key in ms access 2012

Tags: ms-access, composite-primary-key

I have a problem with composite primary key.
I have this situation:

[image: model]

And I don't understand how make it in ms access.

I tried to make it but ms access creates two relationships instead of one:

[image: model acccess]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no error.

That (the lower picture) is how a relation between two composite keys is displayed.

Comment: Although late, I thank you for the clarification. In fact it was not a mistake.

Comment: Wauw! Never too late. Have a nice weekend.